# Django Full image is not loading

Tags: django, static

I am doing the Tango with Django tutorial. I am using Django version 3.1.1. I was able to get my image to load on the local link 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/rango.jpg'

I am not getting it to load on to the index.html the code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %} 
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Rango</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rango says...</h1>
        <div>
            hey there partner! <br />
            <strong>{{ boldmessage }} </strong><br />
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="/rango/about/">About</a><br />
            <img src="{% static
                'images/rango.jpg' %}" 
                alt="Picture of Rango" /> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I did try removing the "alt=" in html but that didn't work.
I do not think the problem is my settings.py, but I'll share some parts of the settings.py anyway.

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates') # this is the file path for templates
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') # this is the file path for static
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
...

#At the very bottom...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: <img src="{% static
                "images/rango.jpg" %}" can you try with double quotes around  ?

Comment: try tp add `STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_DIR`

Comment: ViLuWi: when I added this `STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_DIR` I got the following error. _ERRORS:  ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting._
Eric Martin: I tried your suggestion but saw no change in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem ended up being how the image html was wrapped. It needs to be one line, like below.

```
<img src="{% static 'images/rango.jpg' %}"alt="Picture of Rango" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago. Applying these changes solved it. Remove `STATIC_DIR` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` from settings.py and replace them with these:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
)
```

Comment: I tried your advise. I was not able to get this to work. Is there something else? Do you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` at the bottom? Thanks for the comments.